# Get external PHP File as string in PHP

Tags: php

How would I get an external PHP file as string without executing it.
I've tried

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
```

But it returns the results of the php file not the script itself.
I've read that using a relative path would do what I want, but that's not viable  as I'm trying to access a script from a different site.  I do have FTP access, but I am hoping there's a simpler method.

Comment: You will not get the PHP-contents of a different site using file_get_contents, because the file will be rendered by the external server before serving it to you.

Comment: There would be major security issues if getting the PHP contents of an externally-hosted file without some kind of authentication were possible...

Comment: You would have to get the content via FTP or some other non-HTTP protocol that would not execute the requested URL via web-server (i.e. execute the script).  That being said.  I would be concerned over this sort of architecture.  Why are you planning to do this?

Comment: this is prevented for good reason!  Imagine if this worked, it would be a security nightmare.

Comment: you can't. if this was possible, you'd be able to download the raw php source for any PHP-based site on the web.

Comment: I am making a really basic cms for personal use to manage several of my personal sites.  I just want to be able to edit all my scripts from a central location.

Comment: Why do you need to get an external PHP file. This may be an X-Y problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have FTP access, I'm not sure how much simpler you can get.

```
$url = "ftp://user:pass@some.domain/file/path";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
```